# How to generate points on spherical surface making equal parts?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, math, geometry, spherical-coordinate

I would like to generate a sphere containing n euqal parts. For example, I want to divide my spherical surface into 36 X 36 parts. Therefore, it should contain 1296 equal parts in total. I do not have clue how to generate points in spherical (3D) space.

I want my plot looking like this but in place of line, I want only point (where two lines intersect).

I know only formulas mentioned below,

```
X = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.cos(THETA)
Y = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.sin(THETA)
Z = R * np.cos(PHI)
```

How would I generate points make equal parts in sphere?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right!..So with equal parts, I mean, I want 36 number of parts vertically and 36 number of parts horizintally.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Do they? The surface of a spherical segment of height h on a sphere of radius R is `2 pi R h`, no matter how close to the pole this segment is. I used to have a link to a cool proof but can't find it right now. See also [Wikipedia: Spherical segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment)

Comment: @MarkDickinson So with equal parts, I mean, I want 36 number of parts vertically and 36 number of parts horizintally

Comment: *I want 36 number of parts vertically and 36 number of parts horizintally* Easy, the corners of the 'squares' are 10° apart in longitude and 5° apart in latitude.  A double loop and Robert, as we say, is your female parent's male sibling.

Comment: I understood that if I want to divide in 36 parts, my square will be 5 degree apart because it has a range between 0 to 180 degree, and my square will be 10 degree apart because longitude has a range of 0 to 360 degree. But I am confuse How can I plot these points in spherical direction using double loop or nested loop.

Comment: @Urvesh If you already know the parametric formula `X = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.cos(THETA);
Y = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.sin(THETA);
Z = R * np.cos(PHI)` and you have already found out that PHI should vary from 0 to 180 in increments of 5, and THETA should vary from 0 to 360 in increments of 10, then what else do you need help with?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't know why you're trying to "win an argument" like that. My point is that OP's requirement "in equal parts" is actually extremely easy to satisfy, by dividing equally along the z-axis instead of dividing equally along the phi-coordinate.

Comment: @Stef Yes, I guess, I know enough to generate points in spherical direction. Right now I am trying to write a code in for loop. If I get any error then I will write here. But Thank you for giving a right path to solve problem!

Comment: @Urvesh No need for `for`-loops. Use `phi = np.linspace(0,180,36+1)` and `theta = np.linspace(0,360,36+1)` and then you can write your formula directly, `X = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.cos(theta);
Y = R * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta);
Z = R * np.cos(phi)`

Comment: @Urvesh and like I was saying, if instead of using `Z = R * np.cos(phi)` you use directly `Z = np.linspace(-R, R, 36+1)` then instead of being split along equal angles, your "squares" will be split equally along the z-axis, and the surface area of all squares will be equal.

Comment: Okay..let me try it. I will write here when I get any doubt or error. Thank you

Comment: @Urvesh Sorry, the multiplication signs `*` in my above comment should instead be `np.outer`, so we get all combinations for (theta, phi). So `x = R * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.cos(theta))`. See the doc: [numpy.outer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)

Comment: @Stef No problem, Thank you for informing. When I applied code with `*` sign then I got only 37 values, then I of applying `np.outer`. After running the code, I got values in numpy array. Now I am trying to plot those values of X, Y, Z coordinates.

Comment: @Urvesh or perhaps a simpler method to avoid `numpy.outer` is to use `numpy.meshgrid`. `theta = np.linspace(0,360,36+1); phi = np.linspace(0,180,36+1); theta,phi = np.meshgrid(theta,phi)`. Then you can write directly `x = R * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)`. See the doc: [numpy.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: Yes, that is a good option to compute coordinate values!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make phi and theta vary along [0,180] and [0,360], you can use `numpy.linspace`.

To get all possible combinations of `cos(phi) * cos(theta)`, you can use the outer product: `numpy.outer`.

To split along equal angles, you should have `z = sin(phi)`; to split into rectangles of equal area, all you need is to split equally along the z-axis.

```py
import numpy as np

def split_sphere(R = 1, horizontal_split = 36, vertical_split = 36, method="equal_angles"):
    theta = np.linspace(0,360,horizontal_split+1)
    if method == "equal_angles":
        phi = np.linspace(0, 180, vertical_split+1)
        c = np.cos(phi)
        s = np.sin(phi)
    elif method == "equal_area":
        c = np.linspace(-1, 1, vertical_split+1)
        s = 1 - c**2
    else:
        raise(ValueError('method must be "equal_angles" or "equal_area"'))
    x = R * np.outer(s, np.cos(theta))
    y = R * np.outer(s, np.sin(theta))
    z = R * np.outer(c, np.ones(horizontal_split+1))
    return x, y, z

def main():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x,y,z = split_sphere()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(x,y,z)
    plt.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

[image: 36x36 points on sphere, split along equal angles]

Comment: This is more concrete and optimized code. Works perfectly! I really appreciate your help!